# Breaking the "Law of Demeter" and possible solution to this issue

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, law-of-demeter

Recently I have read about the "Law of Demeter".

Let's suppose we have:

```
public class Restaurant {
     private String name;
     private Address address;

    // getters and setters...
}

public class Address {
     private String city;
     private String postalCode;

     // getters and setters...
}
```

Let's suppose somewhere else I have:

```
public void myFoo(Restaurant restaurant) {
     ...
     String restaurantCity = restaurant.getAddress().getCity(); // Breaking Demetra?
     ...
}
```

Am I breaking the Law of Demeter?

I think so because myFoo is "touching" an object (`address`) which is not a class attribute.

My solution is to modify as follows:

```
public class Restaurant {
     private String name;
     private Address address;

     // getters and setters...

     // added
     public String getCity() {
          return this.getAddress().getCity();
     }
}

public void myFoo() {
     ...
     String restaurantCity = restaurant.getCity();
     ...
}
```

Is that correct?

Comment: The law of *Demeter*? In which case: yes; and yes.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't understood your comment. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean are you referring the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)? That's what you seem to be describing, and I'm not familiar with any Law of Demetra.

Comment: Yes, Law of Demeter

Comment: It would help people answer the question if you would quickly summarize the Law of Demeter.

Comment: Using ``restaurant.getAddress().getCity()`` may be following the Law of Demeter, depending on how it's interpreted. There are multiple points of view.